macOS Finder Sync Extension with electron.js: sync status icons issue
We have 1 electron application which we are using on both Windows and Mac.
We wanted to give sync status icons as OneDrive provides. For MAC, we took help from this documentation - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html
Our sync status icons are visible now and its working properly.
We are facing 1 issue here-
Let's say, we are syncing files inside folder - /Users/<user_name>/parentFolder/child_folder
and above mentioned folder is also opened through Finder of macOS.
Here, in above scenario, all process of applying sync status icon runs successfully, but as mentioned folder is opened in Finder, hence, sync status icons are not visible instantly.
To see sync status icons, we have go back to another different folder and come back again to above mentioned folder in Finder, then only we are able to see sync status icons.
In short, when mentioned folder is opened in Finder, then sync status icons are not visible, but its visible when we change different folder in Finder and again switch back to our mentioned folder from Finder.
Can anyone please help us here to find out issue and fix it?
Please do let us know if need any other info or detailed info.
